# JNI : When should I release resources?

Tags: java-native-interface

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_xxx_xpdf_PdfToText_getTextOnly(JNIEnv *env, jclass obj,
                                                                 jstring pdf_path) {
  const char *pdf = env->GetStringUTFChars(pdf_path, 0);

  std::string content;
  unsigned int i = getTextFromPDF(pdf, &content);

  env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(pdf_path, pdf);

  const char *result = content.c_str();
  jstring str = env->NewStringUTF(result);

  return str;
}
```

Do I need to relase `str` and `content` here ? And why ?

Answer (score 2):

No. `str` refers to a Java object which continues to exist beyond this JNI method, as it is the return value. `content` is a C++ local object which is auto-destroyed when its declaring scope exits.

Comment: I know it's a bit old thread, but when the `str` in op would not be returned, does it need to be released explicitly?